# Import-CSV Nested HashTable

Tags: powershell

Say I have a CSV file that looks like:

```
arch,osversion,kb
32,6.1,KB1,http://kb1
32,6.2,KB2,http://kb2
64,6.1,KB3,http://kb3
64,6.2,KB4,http://kb4
```

How would this CSV get imported into structured hash table that looks like this?

```
32 -> 6.1 -> KB1 -> http://kb1
   -> 6.2 -> KB2 -> http://kb2
64 -> 6.1 -> KB3 -> http://kb3
   -> 6.2 -> KB4 -> http://kb4
```

The command below yields http://kb1:

```
$data['32'].'6.1'.'KB1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably Group-Object is what you want.

```
$csv = @'
arch,osversion,kb,link
32,6.1,KB1,http://kb1
32,6.2,KB2,http://kb2
64,6.1,KB3,http://kb3
64,6.2,KB4,http://kb4
'@

$data = ConvertFrom-Csv $csv

$data | Group-Object -Property arch
```

Or maybe closer to what you want to query:

```
$groups = $data | Group-Object -Property arch, osversion, kb
($groups | ? Name -eq '32, 6.1, KB1').Group.link
```

You could even use variables...

```
$a = '32'
$o = '6.1'
$k = 'KB1'

($groups | ? Name -eq "$a, $o, $k").Group.link
```

From this, you can determine if such a pattern works for you.

Comment: thanks, the idea is not to use where-object by accessing it directly as opposed to filtering it.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting task. The following code snippet could help (solves `arch` duplicates):

```
Remove-Variable data*, aux* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ### clear for debugging purposes
$datacsv = @'
arch,osversion,kb,link
32,6.1,KB1,http://kb1
32,6.2,KB2,http://kb2
64,6.1,KB3,http://kb3
64,6.2,KB4,http://kb4
'@
$datac = ConvertFrom-Csv $datacsv
$datag = @{}
$datac | ForEach-Object {
    $auxLeaf    = @{ $_.kb = $_.link }
    $auxParent  = @{ $_.osversion = $auxLeaf }
    if ( $datag.ContainsKey( $_.arch) ) {
        $auxParent += $datag[ $_.arch]
    }
    $datag.Set_Item( $_.arch, $auxParent )
}
```

Then, `$datag['32']['6.1']['KB1']` returns desired value `http://kb1`

Another interesting problem: solve `osversion` duplicates in a particular `arch`:

```
Remove-Variable data*, aux* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ### clear for debugging purposes
$datacsv = @'
arch,osversion,kb,link
32,6.1,KB1,http://kb1
32,6.1,KB5,http://kb5
32,6.1,KB7,http://kb7
32,6.2,KB2,http://kb2
64,6.1,KB3,http://kb3
64,6.2,KB4,http://kb4
'@
$datac = ConvertFrom-Csv $datacsv
$datag = @{}
$datac | ForEach-Object {
    $auxLeaf   = @{ $_.kb = $_.link }
    $auxParent = @{ $_.osversion = $auxLeaf }
    if ( $datag.ContainsKey( $_.arch) ) {
        if ( $datag[$_.arch].ContainsKey($_.osversion) ) {
            $auxLeaf  += $datag[$_.arch][$_.osversion]
            $auxParent = @{ $_.osversion = $auxLeaf }
        } else {
            $auxParent += $datag[ $_.arch]
        }
    }
    $datag.Set_Item( $_.arch, $auxParent )
}
```

The latter code snippet is roughly equivalent to

```
$datag =
@{
    '32' = @{ '6.1' = @{ 'KB1'='http://kb1';
                         'KB5'='http://kb5';
                         'KB7'='http://kb7' };
              '6.2' = @{ 'KB2'='http://kb2' }
            };
    '64' = @{ '6.1' = @{ 'KB3'='http://kb3' };
              '6.2' = @{ 'KB4'='http://kb4' } 
            }
 }
```

Comment: This is very well thought out and works. Thanks very much.